# Dotnet and JavaScript url encoding

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, url, urlencode, encodeuricomponent

The Following code returns `http://localhost:23843/home/GetBooksTitles?partial=yes&amp;typeofbook=livre` instead of `http://localhost:23843/home/GetBooksTitles?partial=yes&typeofbook=livre`. It returns `&amp;` instead of `&`.

How do I tell dotnet not to encode url like that ?

```
    var url = '<%: Url.Action("GetBooksTitles","home", 
               new { partial="yes",typeofbook="livre"},"http")%>';
        alert(url);
```

Note: I don't want to user `url.replace('&amp;','&')`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Html.Raw`

```
var url = '<%: Html.Raw(Url.Action("GetBooksTitles","home", 
               new { partial="yes",typeofbook="livre"},"http"))%>';
alert(url);
```

By default Asp.net MVC engine will encode string automatically. in case if you want raw string you can use Html.Raw.